# How can I migrate a git-svn codebase to another device?

Tags: git, svn, migration, windows-10, git-svn

We've been assigned new laptops at work and I'm looking to move my git-svn repository to the new device. The svn server URL or my credentials haven't changed.

The problem is `git svn rebase` doesn't want to work any more - it just hangs, and `git svn fetch` fetches everything from revision one. It's an old codebase of over 70k commits and re-importing everything takes at least 3 working days (doing about 20k commits a day), as I've had to rediscover.

I'm aware of shallow cloning but I'm interested in migrating the existing local repository.

Things I've tried:

- Copy the git repo from the old laptop to the new laptop
- `git clone` the old git repo from the new laptop

In both cases I made sure my global git config is the same and that svn-remote points to the correct URL.

**Clarification**:

- The code is hosted on svn. I use git-svn privately
- I'm looking to migrate my personal copy of the codebase, not the svn repository

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should simply be able to copy your working directory together with the `.git` subdirectory from your old workstation to the new one. I used this as a workaround for slow git-svn copy on windows machines earlier.

Comment: I did that, unfortunately fetch starts from rev 0 and rebase doesn't work. I left it running for a while, didn't seem to do anything, it just hanged there. My svn repo has a custom structure, so that might've tripped it up